# max-width not working for IE 11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I´m very new designer and created my own WordPress theme and it works as expected on FireFox, Chrome and Opera. The problem arrives with InternetExplorer (i´m using Windows 7 with IE 11).

Seems that InternetExplorer 11 don't understand the max-width CSS. I have this CSS:

```css
.vi-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.vi-content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

The HTMl code is something like:

```html
<div class="vi-container">
    <header class="vi-header">Header stuff</header>
    <main class="vi-content" itemtype="http://schema.org/Blog" itemprop="mainContentOfPage" itemscope="" role="main">
        <article class="post-content-wrap" itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting" itemprop="blogPost" itemscope=""></article>
        <!-- more articles with contents -->
        <aside class="vi-sidebar" itemtype="http://schema.org/WPSideBar" itemscope="" role="complementary"></aside>
    </main>
</div>
```

The max-width 1200px is totaly ignored by InternetExplorer. You can see it in live loading my webpage in IE and other browser to compare. For example: http://www.vozidea.com/limpia-la-base-de-datos-wordpress-con-wp-sweep

And here an example JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z4s01yxz/

I found other articles into StackOverflow about max-width issues on IE, but couldn't achieve a fix bymyself, that's why i´m requesting help. Hope that someone can give me a hand with this, thanks in advance.

The actual problem is that in InternetExplorer the webpage expands to fill all the width because max-width is ignored. You can check this image to see the difference: i.imgur.com/kGr8wk1.jpg

P.S: Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Please specify what the actual problem is (ignore is not sufficient) and provide a code sample **in the question** to demonstrate it. An offsite link is not adequate.

Comment: Done @Paulie_D , i added more information, example code and screens. Hope tha this is enougth.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I think your problem is not coming from `max-width` but from `main` element...

The `main` element is not fully supported by IE11 ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main)).

2 solutions :

- Change your `<main>` element to a `<div>`. Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/z4s01yxz/2/
- Add `main { display: block; }` to your CSS. Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/z4s01yxz/1/

Comment: You are my hero, thanks for the solution. Sadly i can't vote up your solution (not enogth reputation) but works very good. Thanks!

Comment: You welcome @Zeokat. Glad to help. If this or any answer has solved your question, you can't vote up but you can [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)  by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Thanks! Helped me too!

Comment: No max-width is only a problem . It's not supported on IE11

Answer (score 0):

I have a condition, in my case, I have image with parent divs in table layout. My condition was to make the image center center and if big image, then max-width to 100%. So, to make the max-width work I had the code below:

```
.cmp-logo{
  diplay:table;
  table-layout:fixed;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.td{
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
.td img{
  display:block;
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:260px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

In above solution, if you remove table-layout:fixed, the max-width does not work in IE11 and below.

Answer (score -1):

use this,

display: -ms-grid;
-ms-grid-columns: max-content;